# How to shift focus in two different Jpanels?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, enter

im independently developing a fully keyboard supported version of openbravo(an opensource erp/pos) so that people that can't afford touchscreen hardware can have a good point of sale for free. So, how do you make in java (netbeans enviroment) to jump between two elements with enter key when they are in different Jpanels?  Specially when there are other buttons involved. Thanks in advance! Ps.Since this a very graphical task here are some fundamental screenshots to understand the problem: http://matheus25.site90.net/first.jpg , http://matheus25.site90.net/second.jpg

Comment: third screenshot http://matheus25.site90.net/third.jpg

Comment: The Netbeans environment shouldn't matter, unless you're suing a GUI builder.  Using a GUI builder will hide more problems that it solves.  I've looked at your pictures, and I'm just not familiar enough with openbravo to understand what you're asking.  Usually, the Tab key shifts from one input field to the next.  The Enter key is used to enter a complete transaction when the GUI is completely filled out.

Comment: Thanks @Gilbert, since this is question too 'particular' do you have any suggestion in general in adding transfer focus when pressing the key related to a default button? this way i would press enter and go to the next field!

Answer (score 0):

See `KeyboardFocusManager.setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(...)`. You should be able to add Enter as a second tab key.

Although, I agree with Gilbert that this will be confusing to users.

Comment: Thanks @camickr but from another answer i saw that "globally registering enter as a focus traversal key will block all per-component bindings to enter (f.i. default button, triggering textfield action" So i wouldnt be able to press the run filter and ok button.